# Can't display words longer than 7 characters, always writes no words

Tags: java

I need it to write out of all the entered words only those that are longer than 7, and if there are none, then it says "no words", but it writes "no words" even when there are words of length 7

```
package example_1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab9{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = Scan().split(" ");
        int words = 0;
        
        for(int i=0; i < input.length;i++) {
            if(input[i].charAt(0) <= 7) {
                System.out.print(input[i] + ' ');
                words++;
            }}
        if (words == 0) {System.out.print( "no words");}
    }
    public static String Scan() {
        String word;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input= ");
        word = scn.nextLine();
        scn.close();
        return word;
    }}
```

Comment: What are you trying to establish with `if(input[i].charAt(0) <= 7)`?

Answer (score 3):

just change your if clause `input[i].charAt(0) <= 7` to `input[i].length() >= 7`

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the for loop to check the length of the word using the length() method of the String class, and only print out words with length greater than 7. You also need to update the condition for the if statement that checks if any words were printed to include words with length exactly 7

Answer (score 0):

The test for string length you implemented, `input[i].charAt(0)` seems to come from other programming languages that would store the string length in the first byte. Java does not do that.

So to get the length of the String in characters, use `input[i].length()`.

Also be aware that characters are not bytes, and bytes are not characters. When reading or writing strings to/from a byte stream such as files, an encoding needs to be set that defines what character<>bye conversion will be used. That allows for example to use the full Unicode character set with UTF-8.